# SQLite SELECT equal to one of two values

Tags: sqlite, select

I am trying to get the messages where the sendID is equal to one of two values. 
This is the statement that I have but it seems to spit out only the messages associated with the first sendID.

```
(SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sendID = ? AND ? ORDER BY timeStamp ASC', id1, id2)
```

Can anyone suggest a good method to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
 WHERE sendID = ? OR sendID = ?
```

or

```
 WHERE sendID IN (?, ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sendID = ? OR sendID = ? ORDER BY timeStamp ASC', id1, id2)
```