# SQLite Query with Python 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have generated a list and able to generate the result:

```
l = [2, 3, 5, 2009 ]

cur1 = cur.execute('SELECT * from table where + or '.join(('Code = ' + str(n) for n in l)))
```

However, I want to put in another query in the same statement as follows:

```
cur1 = cur.execute('SELECT * from table where '
**'Timestamp in (select max(timestamp) from table)'**
+ ' or '.join(('Code = ' + str(n) for n in l)))
```

but generated

```
 sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Code": syntax error.
```

Please kindly advise how I can fit Timestamp statement into the first statement in order to focus on the query result which I want.

Comment: `'Code = 2SELECT * from table where + or Code = 3SELECT * from table where + or Code = 5SELECT * from table where + or Code = 2009'
` that's what your 1st query looks like, and you're saying that's working ?

Comment: I am new to sqlite and Python......  :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first was false and the second is of course false too.

```
>>> 'SELECT * from table where + or '.join(('Code = ' + str(n) for n in l))
>>> 'Code = 2SELECT * from table where + or Code = 3SELECT * from table where + or Code = 5SELECT * from table where + or Code = 2009'
```

It's not a valid SQL statement.

[SQLite SELECT equal to one of two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159323/sqlite-select-equal-to-one-of-two-values)

The right query statement should be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Code in ('2', '3', '5', '2009')
```

You will get it with:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE Code in ?', str(tuple(str(i) for i in l)))
```

Now you can use the same parameter for your second statement.

*P/S: There is a better solution, but i don't have SQLite database to check it.*

Comment: julivico: There is a sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
from your code... Please help...

Comment: Sorry, it should be `?` instead of `%`